# how to use conditions in php classes

Tags: php

I am new to php (oops). i m getting confuse to using php condition in (php)classes.
i just want to validate my php form using classes. somebody please help me to make my script work.

```
class Connect
{
    public $host = "localhost";
    public $username = "root";
    public $password = "";
    public $database = "cls";
    public $mcon;
    public $mdcon;

    function __construct()
    {
        $con = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);

        if(!$con)
        {
            die;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->mcon= $con;
            return $this->mcon;
        } 
    }

    function Seldb()
    {
        $condb = mysqli_select_db($this->mcon, $this->database);
        $this->mdcon= $condb;
        return $this->mdcon;     
    } 

    function Ucheck($uname, $upass)
    {
        $check = "select * from ut  WHERE u_name ='$uname' and u_pass ='$upass'";
        if ($uresult= mysqli_query($mdcon,$check))
        {
            $urows= mysqli_num_rows($uresult);
        }   
        if ($urows == 1)
        {
            $_SESSION['uname'] = $uname;
            $_SESSION['auth'] = 1 ;
            $_SESSION['check'] = 'sesscheck' ;
            header('Location:http://google.com/');
        }
        else
        {
            $war = "PLEASE enter username and password again.";  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: Is `session_start();` loaded?

Comment: yes ..on index.php where m going to use this script.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
if ($uresult= mysqli_query($this->$mdcon,$check))
```

instead of

```
if ($uresult= mysqli_query($mdcon,$check))
```

You need to use the `this` keyword , else it will give you an `undefined variable` notice.

---

#### Rewriting code. (Added an else with mysqli_error() to check if your query fails)

```
function Ucheck($uname, $upass)
    {
        $check = "select * from ut  WHERE u_name ='$uname' and u_pass ='$upass'";
        if ($uresult= mysqli_query($this->Seldb(),$check))
        {
            $urows= mysqli_num_rows($uresult);
        } else { mysqli_error($this->Seldb());}  //<----- Added This
```

Comment: So far its ok , Also check if you have started `session_start();` on top of your code as [`Fred-ii`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii) mentioned.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: mdcon in C:\wamp\www\a1final\classes.php on line 31

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\wamp\www\a1final\classes.php on line 31

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\a1final\classes.php on line 31

Comment: u mean with index.php and with classes page ??

Comment: Seems like your query is failing. Are you passing the paramaters correctly.? Rewrited the code , can u do the changes ?